# remote json read doesn't work in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I need to parse the json output from here http://kalpa.freeoda.com/news/news_feed.php

Following is the code I have written,

```
$.getJSON("http://kalpa.freeoda.com/news/news_feed.php", function(data){
        alert('Received news");
});
```

But I don't get an alert when I run this code.

Any support to get this working is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can't get JSON from a remote server - you need to get JSONP, or Padded JSON.  You need to add a `callback=?` in the url or use `.ajax`

Comment: Same origin policy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 3):

Try this:-

live demo

http://jsfiddle.net/YFtvU/9/

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
                data: {
                    q: "select * from json where url ='http://kalpa.freeoda.com/news/news_feed.php'",
                    format: "json"
                },
                dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {

                alert(JSON.stringify(data));


            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Sorry no data found.");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W9tSv/6/)

```
            $.getJSON("http://kalpa.freeoda.com/news/news_feed.php?callback=?", null, function (data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            });
```

Comment: getting data from remote site u must use `datatype` as `jsonp`

Comment: While this would work if the service supported jsonp, the given service does not support jsonp. Also, document.ready is not needed to make an ajax request.

Comment: @dianuj jsonp is assumed when using getJSON and an external url, you don't have to specify it in this case.

Comment: @geek thank you and all other as well. I got my code working. I used ajax with "callback=?" and I modified my php file to echo jsonp instead of json.